# Scroll to element in scrollable div only if the element is not visible on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent div with fixed height, inside this div I have other child divs with data, so if I edit one of them and click "Save" I need to scroll that edited div to view.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">1</div>
   <div class="child">2</div>
   <div class="child">3</div>
   <div class="child">4</div>
   <div class="child">5</div>
   <div class="child selected-div">6</div>
</div>
```

I tried using Position and Offset but both did not work correctly, and Parent div always scrolls to wrong positions.

```
$('.parent').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".selected-div").position().top
    },
        'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

you must write like this in your JQuery Code

```
$('.parent').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".selected-div").scrollTop()
   },
      'slow');
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the code you wrote will always scroll to top. I need to scroll to the position of selected div.

Comment: you can use .scroll